# R prints null at end of write.table output

Tags: r, csv, null

I have an R script which writes a table with the following line:

```
print(write.table(dat, sep =",", row.names=FALSE))
```

The result if I pipe to CSV (or print to STDOUT on the command line) is:

[image]

How can this be avoided?

Thanks for your insight <3

Comment: The NULL is probably coming from the `print()`. Is that necessary? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick, you were correct, it was because of using ```print()```

Comment: @Mr.Thorn Answering your own question (not in a comment) and accepting this answer as a solution is a good way to close a question on SO. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using `print()` solved the issue